# Is there the korean version of 'As' for when cause or reasonings

Tags: grammar, translation, adverbs

I was browsing ths Google to see if theres this exact word for nuance and meaning 'As' for reasons or effects rather than comparisons, but I found none, example:

*'**As** the sun slowly sets, Shin-Hye is walking on the streets to buy some tteokbokki before heading home'*

To use, while, when, or since is pretty **no** **no** so, I need to know the right word or grammar for this word

Comment: These kinds of words are pretty nebulous and you won't find an exact match between different languages. I'm not sure if you're looking for a single Korean word that matches "as" in multiple different sentences, but if that is the case, there is no such a word.

Answer (score 0):

Your example describes two things happening in parallel. Common expressions for that are -(을) 때 or -(으)면서 (less common), but these are like "when" or "while" which you want to exclude.

There are other phrases like -(으)ㅁ에 따라 or -는 가운데, which are typically used for events that are more closely tied or which have stronger cause-and-effect relationship.

E.g.

- 팬데믹이 끝나감에 따라 관광 산업이 다시 살아나기 시작했다 = As the pandemic came to an end, the tourism industry began a revival.
- 많은 대기업이 뛰어드는 가운데 전기차 경쟁이 불붙었다 = As a slew of big companies jumped in / With a slew of big companies jumping in, electric vehicle competition got red hot.

The two events in your examples are not closely related.  For such things connecting them with a simple -고 (and) might be more natural.

- 해는 뉘엿뉘엿 지고 신혜는 귀갓길에 떡볶이를 사려고 거리를 걷고 있다.

Or you can use -(으)ㄹ 때 (when, while, as) or -는 가운데 (as).

- 해가 뉘엿뉘엿 질 때 귀갓길의 신혜는 떡볶이를 사려고 거리를 걷고 있다.
- 해가 뉘엿뉘엿 지는 가운데 귀갓길의 신혜는 떡볶이를 사려고 거리를 걷고 있다.

As you can see, there are multiple expressions with different nuances. You can't just blindly equate "as" with a single phrase.